# Is the finite support product of specializing Aronszajn trees' forcings ccc?

Tags: trees, forcing

Given a tree $(T,\sqsubset)$, a map $\varphi: T\longrightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ is order preserving if and only if $\varphi(x)<\varphi(y)$ iff $x\sqsubset y$. The forcing notion $Fn^{op}(T,\mathbb{Q})$ of all finite partial function from $T$ on the rationals which are order preserving is ccc and adds a order preserving map from $T$ on the rationals in the generic extension.

On the sequel denote by $\mathcal{A}$ the class of all Aronszajn trees. My question is the following. Why the forcing notion $\prod^{fin}_{T\in\mathcal{A}} Fn^{op}(T,\mathbb{Q})$ is ccc? To see this my strategy was to prove that for every $\mathcal{I}\in [\mathcal{A}]^{<\omega}$ the product $\prod_{T\in\mathcal{I}} Fn^{op}(T,\mathbb{Q})$ is ccc. I also know that the tree product $T'=\oplus_{T\in\mathcal{I}} T$ is Aronszajn and hence $Fn^{op}(T',\mathbb{Q})$ is ccc but, is there any relation between the posets $Fn^{op}(T',\mathbb{Q})$ and $\prod^{fin}_{T\in\mathcal{A}} Fn^{op}(T,\mathbb{Q})$ which allows to see that the last one is ccc?

Every comment would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Given $T_0, T_1$ two Aronszajn trees, we show $S(T_0)\times S(T_1)$ is c.c.c. (here $S(T)$ is the specalizing foring). It follows from the following facts:

1. $S(T_0)\times S(T_0)$ is c.c.c. The reason is that $\Vdash_{S(T_0)} T_0$ does not have an uncountable branch. Hence $\Vdash_{S(T_0)}S(T_0)$ is c.c.c
2. If $S(T_0)\times S(T_0)$ is c.c.c, then $S(T_0)$ satisfies $\omega_1$-approximation property, so in particular, it does not add any cofinal branch to any ground model branchless trees of height $\omega_1$. Hence $\Vdash_{S(T_0)} T_1$ does not have any uncountable branch, thus $S(T_1)$ is c.c.c.
3. $\Vdash_{S(T_0)} S(T_1)$ is c.c.c., so $S(T_0)\times S(T_1)$ is c.c.c.